# Как подключить все классы, а не перезаписывать главный последним подключённым

Tags: php

Есть например главный класс и классы которые его расширяют:

```
class mainClass {
    public static function some_function() {
        $obj = new mainClass();
        $obj->property1 = 'Value of property1';
        $obj->property2 = 'Value of property2';
        return $obj;
    }
}
$mainObj = new mainClass();

class addedClass1 extends mainClass {
    public static function some_function() {
        $obj = mainClass::some_function();
        $obj->property1 = 'Overrided value of property1';
        return $obj;
    }
}

class addedClass2 extends mainClass {
    public static function some_function() {
        $obj = mainClass::some_function();
        $obj->property2 = 'Overrided value of property2';
        return $obj;
    }
}

$arrayOfClasses = ['addedClass1','addedClass2'];
foreach($arrayOfClasses as $class) {
    $mainObj = new $class();
}

echo $mainObj->some_function()->property1 .'<br>';
echo $mainObj->some_function()->property2;
```

В данном случае `class addedClass2` как и нужно перезаписывает `$obj->property2`, но при этом `addedClass1` больше не перезаписывает `$obj->property1`

Т.е. сейчас получаю:

```
Value of property1
Overrided value of property2
```

А нужно:

```
Overrided value of property1
Overrided value of property2
```

Как сделать чтобы все классы подключались и перезаписывали каждый свое отдельное свойство?

ps. addedClass'ы на самом деле будут подключаться все с отдельной директории, поэтому ни их названия, ни общее количество неизвестны, эти два только для примера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы в цикле перезаписываете переменную $mainObj, и на выходе из цикла в ней сохраняется значение после последней итерации. Чтобы получить оба объекта, можно либо собирать их в массив в этом же цикле *(вариант №1)*, либо объявить в классе статические свойства, и записывать в эти свойства необходимые значения *(вариант №2)* :

> Вариант №1

```
class mainClass
{
    public static function some_function() {
        $obj = new mainClass();
        $obj->property1 = 'Value of property1';
        $obj->property2 = 'Value of property2';
        return $obj;
    }
}

class addedClass1 extends mainClass
{
    public static function some_function() {
        $obj = mainClass::some_function();
        $obj->property1 = 'Overrided value of property1';
        return $obj;
    }
}

class addedClass2 extends mainClass
{
    public static function some_function() {
        $obj = mainClass::some_function();
        $obj->property2 = 'Overrided value of property2';
        return $obj;
    }
}

$arrayOfClasses = ['addedClass1','addedClass2'];

foreach ($arrayOfClasses as $class) {
    $mainObj[] = new $class();
}

echo $mainObj[0]->some_function()->property1 .'<br>';
echo $mainObj[1]->some_function()->property2;
/*
Overrided value of property1
Overrided value of property2
*/
```

> Вариант №2

```
class mainClass
{
    public static $property1;
    public static $property2;

    public static function some_function() {
        self::$property1 = 'Value of property1';
        self::$property2 = 'Value of property2';
    }
}

class addedClass1 extends mainClass
{
    public static function some_function() {
        mainClass::$property1 = 'Overrided value of property1';
    }
}

class addedClass2 extends mainClass
{
    public static function some_function() {
        mainClass::$property2 = 'Overrided value of property2';
    }
}

$arrayOfClasses = ['addedClass1', 'addedClass2'];

foreach ($arrayOfClasses as $class) {
    $class::some_function();
}

echo addedClass1::$property1 .'<br>';
echo addedClass1::$property2;
/*
Overrided value of property1
Overrided value of property2
*/
```

Comment: Спасибо! В конце правда лучше `echo mainClass::$property...` И еще вопрос: а можно ли как то внутри какого то addedClassX добавить например `$property3`, присвоить ей значение и прилепить ее к mainClass чтобы вывести в конце через `echo mainClass::$property3` ?

Comment: @stckvrw _В конце правда лучше echo mainClass::$property_ - разницы нет, т.к. свойство `propertyN` доступно и там, и там. На счёт вопроса: _а можно ли как то внутри какого то addedClassX добавить например $property3, присвоить ей значение и прилепить ее к mainClass чтобы вывести в конце через echo mainClass::$property3_ - если вам нужно добавлять значения в свойства динамически, то можно действовать по аналогии с массивами -- объявить одно свойство "массив", и оперировать его ключами: [смотреть пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3dcc94dde4dd8a7d795314799276a5c935aee1a)

Comment: @stckvrw [пример добавления нового элемента в свойство класса](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d5c7960df020394b437600c775512a9ce7d7347e)

Comment: @stckvrw ещё пример: [добавление внутри класса](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13fab680b02f4d716148202f3f84cb60fd223b51)

Comment: @stckvrw дописал пример с перегрузкой свойства [смотреть демо](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/42d2ad6262788a20b0ac471b554a423b218e005e)

Comment: А почему [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943267/load-a-class-on-the-fly-with-php#comment15910922_11943267) в комментах под вопросом пишут что подключение плагинов путем динамического расширения главного класса классами плагинов является неправильным?

Comment: @stckvrw я в ооп не эксперт, однако в том комментарии идёт речь о динамическом изменении родительского класса, а не о его расширении с помощью дочерних классов.

Comment: А в чем же разница? Приведите плз самый простой пример _изменения_ в отличии от _расширения_

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70749/discussion-between--and-stckvrw).